# New to Ubuntu (linux). Would like to install a printer. A bit clueless

Tags: 13.10, printing, canon, install-from-source, pixma

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my old Dell desktop. It runs fine and I like the Ubunte experience. I found most software using the 'software centre'. But not for my Canon printer. I went to their website and they do have a linux driver. I downloaded it and it is called: Linux_Print_Filterv270.tgz

I unpacked it and got a folder with a number of .rpm files. I have not clue what to do next. Could you help me with it?

Edit: I am a bit further. I installed Alien to convert the .rmp file to a .deb file. I read on a website to use this command but get an error...

```
sudo -k cnijfilter-common-2.70-2.src.rpm
[sudo] password for michel: 
sudo: cnijfilter-common-2.70-2.src.rpm: command not found
```

Also tried @Jos: sudo alien cnijfilter-common-2.70-2.src.rpm --> File "cnijfilter-common-2.70-2.src.rpm" not found.

Edit 15.55: I entered the alien but it still doesn work
sudo alien -k cnijfilter-common-2.70.2.src.rpm
Opdracht ‘-sudo’ niet gevonden, bedoelde u:
 Opdracht ‘sudo’ uit pakket ‘sudo-ldap’ (universe)
 Opdracht ‘sudo’ uit pakket ‘sudo’ (main)
-sudo: opdracht niet gevonden
(not found)

Edit: 16:30
I had forgotten to switch directories (already had a gut feeling about that). I was then able to have Alien to create a .deb file. When installing that I got a message that it was of bad quality. I choose to ignore and the installation failed. The file I got from @Jos was also of bad quality but it did install, finally. Thanks for all the help guys! I sure hope installing drivers will not always be this difficult for a newbie.

Comment: What is the exact model of your printer and how do you intend to connect it: LAN, USB?

Comment: The model is Canon PIXMA iP4300. It is connected by USB.

Comment: According to [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon), the [following instructions should work.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/CanonPrinters/CanonPixmaIP4200#preview) Note the instructions seem to be a bit old. Use the newer files you have downloaded if possible.

Comment: You forgot the word "alien" in your last command.

Comment: Hi Mike, for educational reasons you should try to manage :), but if you will not, download it here:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/linux-print-filterv270_1-2_all.deb I converted it.

Comment: @Jacob you are my hero! But would also like to know what Iḿ doing wrong. Is it that Iḿ not pointing to the folder where it is? Or is that Windows thinking?

Comment: @Mike ooops, I uploaded the wrong file. IF you didn't manage yet, you can install this file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/cnijfilter-ip4300_2.70-3_i386.deb

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install the newer Ubuntu version. With a working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-common
```

It installs a newer version, as well, 3.80-1. Then you should be able to install your printer through System Settings > Printers.

Comment: where did you find that one?

Comment: In Synaptic where I searched for cnij.

Comment: It can find that either it says

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Chili. More errors though

Comment: It was altready the latest version. Then I pressed J and:

Comment: Instellen van cnijfilter-common (2.70-2) ...
chown: ongeldige gebruiker: ‘adminv270:adminv270’
chown: ongeldige gebruiker: ‘adminv270:adminv270’
dpkg: error processing cnijfilter-common (--configure):
 subproces installed post-installation script gaf een foutwaarde 1 terug
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @Mike You are still trying to install the rpm with alien. It is not required. Install the Ubuntu version instead.

Comment: Chili I get a notification that cnijfilter-common is already updated and then a bunch errors more when I press 'J'

Comment: The errors you posted above? Or some other? It is difficult to troubleshoot without seeing them. You may wish to paste them here and give us the link in your reply: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Yes the errors above.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7151928/

Comment: The 'user adminv270' and 'group adminv270' warnings are warnings that the user/group indicated in the rpm are non-existent on your system, so the system did the proper thing and installed them with root as owner. Is your printer working as expected? If so, we need do nothing. If it is not, we'll try something else.